# Choose XSLT processor depending on XSLT version

Tags: java, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, saxon, xalan

My application has many old stylesheets written in `XSLT 1.0` and the new ones are being written in `XSLT 2.0`.

With `Saxon 9.6` many of the old stylesheets are not functioning properly, especially the ones using EXSLT `set:distinct`. Hence, I want to continue using `Xalan` to transform the old `XSLT 1.0` stylesheets, but use `Saxon` for the new `XSLT 2.0` stylesheets.

In Java what is the best way to read the `xsl:stylesheet/@version` attribute of the XSL file before deciding on the `TransformerFactory`?

As of now, the application creates a `StreamSource` from the absolute path of the XSL file.

```
Source xslSource = new StreamSource(xslFilePath);
String version = ...; // TODO Get XSLT version of XSL file

TransformerFactory transformerFactory;

if ("2.0".equals(version)) {
    transformerFactory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
} else {
    transformerFactory = new org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably as good a way as any. Note that if you write a SAX ContentReader to access the xsl:stylesheet/@version, you can abort the parsing as soon as the version is known by throwing a SAXException.